# parallax banner not functioning with overflow-x:hidden

Tags: html, css, overflow, parallax

I had a parallax banner working on my site but after trying to fix empty vertical space on the page by using

```
body{
    overflow-x: hidden;
}
```

it stopped functioning...heres my parallax code:

**HTML**

```
<div class="headerimg">
    <h2 class = "headertitle">
    <span class = "spacer"><p class= "headertext">HEADER</p></span>
    </h2>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.headerimg{
   position: relative;
   background:url('http://i.imgur.com/soTLu5u.jpg') fixed;
   background-size: cover;
   height:500px;
}


.headertitle{ 
   position: absolute; 
   top:50%;
   left: 50%;
   transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);

}

.headertitle span.spacer{ 
   color: white; 
   font: bold 24px/45px Helvetica, Sans-Serif; 
   letter-spacing: -1px;  
   background: rgb(0, 0, 0); /* fallback color */
   background: rgba(253,239,145,0.5);
   display: inline-block;
  /*--THIS MAKES THE TRANSPARENT BLOCK --*/ 
   padding: 50px;
 }

.headertext{
    font-size: 150px;

}
```

can anyone point out what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: it works for me but you can try to add a max-width of 100vw to your body and delete overflow-x

Comment: @CedricGourville thanks for this tip! the max-width didn't work but I added both width: 100vw and overflow-x:hidden and it worked!

Comment: oh I find your problem !! body { padding : 0; margin : 0; } no need max-width. After that if you want to see the parallax you need to set a more higher height https://jsfiddle.net/Tanikimura/rzajdaLp/1/